# eigen: get next block of the matrix with stride =2

Tags: c++, eigen

Does Eigen support getting next block with stride =2?

I observed the default behavior is with stride =1 in this:

```
m.block<F, F>(i, j)
```

I am looking for solution which can give me next block with non-1 stride as shown in the animated `Convolution Demo` in the following link:

http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/

If Eigen does not support it, what would be a good way of indexing to get next block with `stride=k`?

Comment: Please do not tag C++ questions as C

Comment: I think the hidden part of the question is whether we should use `new int[][]` or `vector<<vector<int>>>` for large matrix. So I tagged it as C++ and C

Comment: Neither does C know the `new` keyword, nor templates though.

Comment: @cpchung Neither. If you’re using Eigen, use their types (e.g. ‘MatrixXi’).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the new slicing and indexing API which will be introduced in Eigen 3.4 (currently in the master branch), you can write Matlab-Style slicing, e.g.,

```
   M(Eigen::seqN(i, Eigen::fix<F>, Eigen::fix<stride>),
     Eigen::seqN(j, Eigen::fix<F>, Eigen::fix<stride>));
```

Returns a block starting at `(i,j)` of size `F x F` with `stride`.
The `Eigen::fix` are optional, but may give slightly better runtime.

Working example: https://godbolt.org/z/wzRdp7

More documentation: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialSlicingIndexing.html

With Eigen 3.3 you need to write some `Map`-based solution as suggested by @AviGinsburg.

Comment: It looks like I’m going to have to update my knowledge (again). Nice.

Answer (score 4):

You can declare the stride with `Eigen::Map` as such:

```
int main()
{
    constexpr int d = 10;
    MatrixXi m(d,d);
    VectorXi lin = VectorXi::LinSpaced(d*d, 0, d*d-1);
    m = Map<MatrixXi>(lin.data(), d, d);
    std::cout << m << "\n\n";

    std::cout << Map<MatrixXi, 0, InnerStride<2>>(m.data() + d + 1, 3, 3) << "\n\n";
    std::cout << Map<MatrixXi, 0, OuterStride<d>>(m.data() + d + 1, 3, 3) << "\n\n";
    // You probably want either this:
    std::cout << Map<MatrixXi, 0, Stride<d, 2>>  (m.data() + d + 1, 3, 3) << "\n\n";
    // or this:
    std::cout << Map<MatrixXi, 0, Stride<2*d, 2>>(m.data() + d + 1, 3, 3) << "\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you can also set the stride at runtime. See [documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Map.html) for details.